# Make a call to another project via @RequestMapping url

Tags: java, spring, connection

I want to connect app A to app B by making a call to the Controller:
App B URL is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v/getInfo")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVInfo() {
    vService.getInfo();
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Both applications are developed by us and not considered yet to integrate both in one.

Is it possible to do this? We are using spring and Java8, and I am confused with what should I start. The app B is also requiring an authentication before calling the URL from the Controller.

Update:
App A is configured the same as App B, and after saving the data to the database we need the call to App B for manipulating those data(the code is in App B). Basically at the end of the App A process we need to start one of the App B processes.

Comment: Provide us details of `app A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make a normal web call using the standard `RestTemplate`.

At the very basic level in app A:

```
@Component
public class AppBCaller {

  @Autowired RestTemplate template;

  public String getInfo() {
    String plainCreds = "username:password";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://whereAppBis/v/getInfo", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
    return response.getBody();
  }
}
```